# Test class for trigger on custom object

Tags: apex, unit-test

I just wrote this trigger and it seems to be working fine in dev, I need to move it into production, however, the test class I wrote passes the test but does not cover the trigger.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a bit green here.

```
trigger PropOwned on Contact (after update) {
        for (Contact c : Trigger.new){
        McLabs2__Ownership__c ownNew= new McLabs2__Ownership__c();
        Contact oldContact = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.id);
        if (c.One_Prop_Owned__c != oldContact.One_Prop_Owned__c && c.One_Prop_Owned__c != null){
        ownNew.McLabs2__Contact__c = c.id;
        ownNew.McLabs2__Property__c = c.One_Prop_Owned__c;
        insert ownNew;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the test class I wrote.

```
   @isTest
     public class TestOwnership {
    static testMethod void createOwnership() {
     McLabs2__Ownership__c ownNew= new McLabs2__Ownership__c();
     ownNew.McLabs2__Contact__c = 'Michael Webb';
     ownNew.McLabs2__Property__c = '131 West 33rd Street';
     insert ownNew;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Testing Wrong Trigger

You're not testing a Contact trigger, you'd be testing a McLabs2__Ownership__c trigger. Your test should create a contact and ensure that a new Ownership record is created.

## Testing Wrong Event

Your event is "after update", not "after insert", so you'd have to create a contact, then update it.

## Using IDs as Strings

Presumably, McLabs2__Contact__c is a contact lookup field. This means you'd need an 18-character ID in your test method, which you'd have already if you had inserted a contact. You can't link a record by it's "name" without some special considerations, so it'd be best to just stick with IDs for now.

## DML inside loops

You need to be following the Aggregate-Query-Update pattern in your trigger. In this case, there's no query, so it's more of just an aggregate-query pattern, but you'll do well to learn how to do this, as it will be your most common optimization technique.

```
trigger PropOwned on Contact (after update) {
    // Aggregate
    McLabs2__Ownership__c[] newRecords = new McLabs2__Ownership__c[0];
    for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.One_Prop_Owned__c != null && record.One_Prop_Owned__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).One_Prop_Owned__c) {
            newRecords.add(
                new McLabs2__Ownership__c(
                    McLabs2__Contact__c=record.Id, 
                    McLabs2__Property__c=record.One_Prop_Owned__c));
        }
    }
    // Query -- we have no queries to perform
    // Insert
    insert newRecords;
}
```

Comment: I'd add that a test class's best practice is checking the end result is what's expected.  E.g:  After "insert ownNew", do a SOQL query returning you the new record(s) and use a system.assert() to ensure the validity of the result.

Answer (score 3):

Your trigger is on `update` `Contact`, but you are doing `insert` `McLabs2__Ownership__c`.

Comment: Thank you so much, however, I am totally lost now. I tried what you had above with some edits it did not seem to work.  Thanks